# RxJS typescript understanding the generic types

Tags: typescript, rxjs

From RxJS docs we can learn that we can create custom operators with the following code:

```
const takeEveryNthSimple = (n: number) => <T>(source: Observable<T>) =>
  source.pipe(filter((value, index) => index % n === 0 ))
```

I want to understand what is the type of generics in this case `<T>(source: Observable<T>)`.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at generic types as a way to have the same function be able to return any type that is passed.

For example, a function that does a `get` request.

```
function doGet<T>(endpoint: string): Observable<T> {
  return Observable.of(fetch(endpoint));
}
```

This function will return an observable of type `T`;

Now, let's say you have a REST api that you can get `Posts`, `Users`, `Tags`. You can use this function with a type definition as such

```
interface Posts {
  //...
}

interface Users {
  //...
}

interface Tags {
  //...
}

doGet<Posts>('/api/posts') => Observable<Posts>;
doGet<Users>('/api/users') => Observable<Users>;
doGet<Tags>('/api/tags') => Observable<Tags>;
```

In the example you provide, the `Observable` that's being passed to the nested function will be of type `T` that is defined in the generic type.

Hopefully this is clear and answers your question.

Comment: In the example the provides https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily, I can't see they provide the T type like you did, so what is the type?

Comment: `T`is just the name that was given to the generic type. Think of it as an undeclared variable, once you use the function and give it a type signature, this signature will be used anywhere the function uses `<T>`. People usually use T as a reference to type, but you could use any letter you like.